# PJAX - AJAX error when space or symbol included in URL?

Tags: jquery, pjax

So I have built a website using PJAX. I have created a search box that will allow me to send a search query via GET, but any time I include a space (%20) or any other symbol, PJAX throws an AJAX error at me, as if the URL isn't found, but then redirect to the page and performs a full reload on the page. Google Chromes developer tools shows that the request is normal, and that the page was found, but for some reason PJAX thinks it's resulting in a 404 error or something. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
$('#searchbox').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = $('#searchbox').val();
        searchvalue = value.replace('Click here to Search...',''); // In case the search box doesn't clear it's value onclick and customer does not notice.
        searchvalue = encodeURIComponent(searchvalue);
        $.pjax({ url: '/category.php?keywords=' + searchvalue, container: '#page-container', timeout: 10000 })
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you use encodeURIComponent(),trim()?

Comment: Yes, doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Fixed it. I was using it to query an eBay API, and the search terms needed to be run through urlencode() before being submitted to eBay, because it was returning a blank document, resulting in PJAX getting confused.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use `trim()` function to  remove unnecessary from front and end

Comment: Well, if I search for "red ball", theres still a space in the query?